# Regex shorthand "\w" difference in Perl5Util (Apache ORO) vs Java regex

Tags: java, regex

Why I am getting different results for below regex expression?

```
String regexp = "^[\\w]+$";
String input = "Ã";

System.out.println(Pattern.matches(regex, input)); // false
System.out.println(new Perl5Util().match("/" + regex + "/", input)); //true
```

How does Perl5Util find the matches of the given character but the Java's regex engine is not?

Comment: _Guess_ `Perl5Util` might have Unicode support

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. I thought about it, but I got confused when Perl5Util fails to find a match for the input data "©". Is that expected from Perl5Util?

Comment: © is not a word character. Why do you expect it to be matched with `\w`?

Answer (score 0):

The `\w` is a *word* character matching shorthand character class, and cannot match `©` since it [belongs to the `\p{So}` (Symbol, Other) category](http://r12a.github.io/uniview/?charlist=%C2%A9#title).

Your test confirms that `Perl5Util` supports Unicode by default.

In Java, you can enable matching all Unicode letters and digits by prepending the pattern with `(?U)` inline modifier, or by compiling the pattern with [`Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` modifier flag](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS).

Comment: Also, check [this mailing list](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jakarta-oro-dev/200101.mbox/%3C20010129001901.41578.qmail@apache.org%3E), it says *Applied a modified version of Takashi Okamoto's Unicode and POSIX character
    class patch to OpCode, Perl5compiler, Perl5Debug, and Perl5Matcher.
  
  o Removed Unicode from the TODO and added improve/optimize Unicode classes.*